# Зависание excel при попытке импортирования списка (list) из Share Point

Tags: excel, sharepoint

Пытаюсь импортировать список из  Share Point в Excel на MS 365.
Размер списка около 2500 строк. Создаю подключение через файл query, после нажатия на кнопку "обновить всё" начинается подключение к источнику, а затем на 40% обработки данных эксель абсолютно зависает.

Примечательно то, что отдельно сама по себе созданная из данных списка таблица обновляется, но при обновлении всех подключений именно на ней ексель впадает в фриз.

Подскажите пожалуйста может кто-то с подобным сталкивался и какие могут быть возможные действия по устранению данной проблемы?